# Gradient text color, using Material-UI <Typography />

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styling

How do I style a `<Typography />` component so that its `font-color` becomes a gradient?

So far what I've tried:

```
const CustomColor = withStyles({
  root: {
    fontColor: "-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
  },
})(Typography);
```

This did not work, so I tried to follow [this](https://cssgradient.io/blog/css-gradient-text/) tutorial, and did this implementation:

```
const CustomColor = withStyles({
  root: {
    fontSize: 20,
    background: "-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
    webkitBackgroundClip: "text",
    WebkitTextFillColor: "transparent",
  },
})(Typography);
```

This also did not work as expected, but at least some sort of gradient showed up.
[image]

Another thing I've tried is:

```
<Typography style={{
    fontSize: 20,
    background: "-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
    webkitBackgroundClip: "text",
    WebkitTextFillColor: "transparent",
  }}> Hello world! </Typography>
```

This kinda worked, but depending on the width of the element the gradient changes. This is an unwanted behavior. Also I would like to stik to a `withStyles` style solution.

Online demo: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-bash-vt4uf?file=/src/App.js)

Any tipps? What have I missed?

Comment: The immediate thing to note is that a gradient is a ‘special kind of’ image, not a color, in CSS. See for example [link] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient() Could you put up a working snippetj so we can see the problem and also describe further what ‘this did not work as expected’ means.

Comment: An image? or you mean the whole code?

Comment: Code that we can run which shows your problem. Use the SO snippet system.

Comment: I'm trying to insert a working template, but I have to admit, I have not a single clue how can I upload my `react` and `material-ui` project to SO.

Comment: @BudaÖrs Try setting up a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or another similar code sharing/collaboration system and share it here.

Comment: Thank you for the awsome suggestion!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

replace the `webkitBackgroundClip` with `WebkitBackgroundClip`. JSS takes the capital letters for webkit.

```
const CustomColor = withStyles({
  root: {
    fontSize: 20,
    background: "-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
    WebkitBackgroundClip: "text",
    WebkitTextFillColor: "transparent"
  }
})(Typography);
```

Here is the working demo:
[image: Edit sad-star-v8u37]

Answer (score 4):

After some time playing around, I come up with this solution...

```
  <Typography
  variant="h1"
  align="left"
  color="grey.700"
  sx={{
    backgroundcolor: "primary",
    backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(45deg, #5514B4, #FF80FF)`,
    backgroundSize: "100%",
    backgroundRepeat: "repeat",
    backgroundClip: "text",
    WebkitBackgroundClip: "text",
    WebkitTextFillColor: "transparent"
  }}
>
  GRADIENT TEXT
</Typography>
```

[Codesandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/magical-fog-z53dnh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble getting this to work with MUI but i got it working with this approach. The key was using backgroundImage instead of background

```
WebkitBackgroundClip: 'text',
WebkitTextFillColor: 'transparent',
backgroundImage: '-webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(222, 53, 76, 0.8), rgba(226, 123, 27, 0.8))',
```